# How to embed more data to candlestick HighChart tooltip?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to show some custom data in my candlestick type of HighChart tooltip. How should I do that?
I've found some solutions for other types of charts but they didn't work for me.

As you know, we have access to value of X, high, low, close and open as default. But I want to embed for example "Name" or "Percent" values to each points to show on tooltip.

I'll appreciate if anyone could answer my question.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can definitely do that. You can access the all the data you pass to the highcharts.

lets say here is a the sample structure of the data you are plotting.

```
{
    low: 19,
    high: 30,
    open: 20,
    close: 28,
    pram2: 'hi',
    param1: 'hello'
}
```

as you already know the default parameters here are open, close, low and high respectively. we want to show 2 more prams called param1 and pram2 in the tooltip. for that we need to have them in the as shown below.

how to access these params from tooltip?
it is quite simple. These is a prameter called formatter in tooltip.

```
tooltip : {
    formatter: function() {
        ........
        ........
        ........
        return something
    }
}
```

this formatter function gets called every tie your mouse goes on to a data point on the plot.

in this formatter function you can access the data of that point as `this.point`. here our additional params can be accessed as `this.point.param1` and `this.point.pram2`

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/ro3770t0/) is a jsfiddle that will help you.

Comment: By setting points as Object I get HighChart Error #20, and turboThreshold won't allow to add more than 1000 point. My chart has around 1 million record. Also I need to have custom data in my tooltip. Do you know how should I set this issue?

Comment: I mean, is there any chance to use Array syntax instead of Object syntax to support million records and also have custom data in tooltip? If NO, how  can I fix highchart error #20?

Comment: @keykan yo can remove turbothreshold. Error#20 can be avoided by setting turbothreshold to 0 to disable it. Please refer this section of the API documentation : http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/plotOptions.candlestick.turboThreshold

Comment: Yeah. You are right. I've set turbothreshold to 0 before asking my question. But it doesn't work. Is there any relation between this setting and addPoint shift parameter? Since I want to keep all bars in my chart, I set shift parameter as false.

Comment: Great!!!
Fixed! My issue was that I didn't set turbothreshold under plot options and I thought I should put it under chart settings... .
Thanks a lot for sparking my brain! :D