# How to fix HighChart Error #20?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a candlestick chart with dynamic data loading. I'm using addPint API for adding new points. Since I need to use some custom data in my tooltips, I set points as Object like as follow:

```
    chart.series[0].addPoint({
        x: time, 
        low: lowValue, 
        high: highValue, 
        open: openValue, 
        close: closeValue, 
        customParameter: myCustomPramameter
});
```

but I get this error that says: `Can't add object point configuration to a long data series` Highcharts error #20: http://www.highcharts.com/errors/20

I've changed Object syntax to Array syntax and my issue has been resolved. But I can not embed any further data to points to use in my tooltips. 
Is there any way to use Array syntax to fix this issue and also I can embed custom data in it for using in my tooltip points?

Here is my current chart options:

```
chart: {
    renderTo: 'chart-container',
    marginRight: 10,
    zoomType: 'x'
},
title: {
    text: 'My Chart'
},
xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    dateTimeLabelFormats: {
        day: '%b - %H:%M:%S',
        second: '%b - %H:%M:%S'
    }
},
yAxis: {
    tickInterval: 0.25,
    opposite: false
},
navigator: {
    adaptToUpdatedData: false
},
scrollbar: {
    liveRedraw: false
},
rangeSelector: {
    buttons: [{
        count: 1,
        type: 'minute',
        text: '1M'
    }, {
        count: 5,
        type: 'minute',
        text: '5M'
    }, {
        count: 15,
        type: 'minute',
        text: '15M'
    }, {
        count: 30,
        type: 'minute',
        text: '30M'
    }, {
        count: 60,
        type: 'minute',
        text: '60M'
    }, {
        count: 2,
        type: 'hour',
        text: '2H'
    }, {
        count: 4,
        type: 'hour',
        text: '4H'
    }, {
        count: 8,
        type: 'hour',
        text: '8H'
    }, {
        count: 1,
        type: 'day',
        text: '1D'
    }, {
        count: 2,
        type: 'day',
        text: '2D'
    }, {
        count: 3,
        type: 'day',
        text: '3D'
    }, {
        count: 4,
        type: 'day',
        text: '4D'
    }, {
        count: 5,
        type: 'day',
        text: '5D'
    }, {
        count: 6,
        type: 'day',
        text: '6D'
    }, {
        count: 7,
        type: 'day',
        text: '7D'
    }, {
        type: 'all',
        text: 'All'
    }],
    inputEnabled: false,
    selected: 0
},
tooltip: {
    formatter: function (e) {
        var point = this.points[0].point;
        return '<div><b>#: </b><span>' + point.barNumber + '</span></div><br /><div><b>Open: </b><span>' + point.open + '</span></div><div><b> Close: </b><span>' + point.close + '</span></div><br /><div><b>High: </b><span>' + point.high + '</span></div><div><b> Low: </b><span>' + point.low + '</span></div><br /><div><b>Custom Param: </b><span>' + point.customParam + '</span></div>'
    }
},
legend: {
    enabled: false
},
exporting: {
    enabled: false
},
series: [
    {
        name: 'My Chart',
        type: 'candlestick',
        data: []
    },
    {
        name: 'Average',
        type: 'spline',
        data: [],
        marker: {
            lineWidth: 2,
            lineColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[3],
            fillColor: 'white'
        },
        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[3]
    }]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the following ticket (Follow up comments),

[How to embed more data to candlestick HighChart tooltip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45161165/how-to-embed-more-data-to-candlestick-highchart-tooltip)

I've found that I can ignore this limitation by setting `turboThreshold` as `0`.

Note that you should set it for plot options! Not chart options.

```
plotOptions: {
    candlestick: {
        turboThreshold: 0
    }
```